# When and when not to use the initialize method in ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I am confused on the initialize method in ruby. I am learning OOP and trying to make a tic-tac-toe game in ruby using OOP. I want to know when to use the initialize method and when not to.

Is it only when i want to make a new object? for example in tic-tac-toe to make the board i would have to do board.new for that i would have to initialize board.

But, lets say i put the method to win would that method need to be initialized even if i do not need to make any objects?

Or is it that I have to initlaize for every new class i make like class board or class player or class win

Comment: Code, like a picture, is worth 10,000 words. "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" is your friend. Show us the minimal code that demonstrates your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `initialize` method is necessary for objects which require something to be done during the object's initialization, that's all. Some objects do not require initialization, for example:

```
class Dog
  def woof
    :arf
  end
end
```

However if you wanted to be able to customize how this dog could bark, you could give it an initializer:

```
class Dog
  WOOF_DEFAULT = :arf

  attr_reader :woof

  def initialize(woof)
    @woof = woof || WOOF_DEFAULT
  end
end
```

Now you can configure it during the initialization:

```
dog = Dog.new(:bork)
dog.woof
# => :bork
```

You don't always need `initialize`, but it is a useful tool for when you do.

In the context of a board, presumably you need to create the board:

```
class Board
  def initialize
    # Create 9 cells, each of which is nil by default
    @cells = Array.new(9, nil)
  end

  def move(x, y, side)
    # Make a move in a cell if the cell is not occupied (||=)
    @cells[x + y * 3] ||= side
  end

  def to_s
    # Produces a string representation of the board state
    @cells.map do |cell|
      cell || ' '
    end.each_slice(3).map do |row|
      row.join(' | ')
    end.join("\n---------\n")
  end
end
```

Where now you have a board which you can use like this:

```
b = Board.new

puts b
#   |   |  
# ---------
#   |   |  
# ---------
#   |   |  

puts

b.move(0,1, 'X')
b.move(1,0, 'O')

puts b
#   | O |  
# ---------
# X |   |  
# ---------
#   |   |
```

Comment: Since there is but one board you might speak to the option of having only class methods and class instance variables, and no instances of the class.

Comment: @CarySwoveland There's nothing wrong with only ever declaring one instance of a class. Having an instance gives you modularity and the *potential* to create more than one board, e.g. for testing.

Comment: btw, there is much truth to your, "A modernized version of Takuan Soho's teachings". I recall experiencing that when I was learning real analysis. It was only when earlier concepts became embedded in my subconscious that I could make progress. One day the clouds parted, seemingly in an instant. Thereafter my brain seemed to automatically ran the embedding process whenever I learned new results. It was weird, but wonderful. I've spoken to others who have had a similar experience.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating two classes, `Board` and `Player`. Taking the later first, there will be two instances of `Player`, one the player marking `'X'`'s and the other the player marking `'O'`'s. The `Player` class has an `initialize` method whose function is to save the mark (`'X'` or `'O'`) the player (instance) will make.

As there is only one board, we could create a single instance of `Board`, as @tadman has done. Another option--the one I've elected--is to construct the class `Board` with three class methods and one *class* instance variable (`@cells`), with no intention of creating a sole instance of the class.

I don't think either approach to the class `Board` is preferred; I just want to make the point that when a class represents a single object that object can be the class itself as opposed to an instance of the class.

You could construct these two classes as follows.

```
WINNERS = 3.times.with_object([]) do |i,a|
   a << [[i,0], [i,1], [i,2]] << [[0,i], [1,i], [2,i]]
end << [[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]] << [[0,2], [1,1],  c[2,0]]
  #=> [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]], [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]],
  #    [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]], [[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1]],
  #    [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]],
  #    [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]]]
```

```
class Board
  @cells = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3, ' ') }

  def self.record_move(r,c,side)
    @cells[r][c] = side
  end

  def self.win?(side)
    WINNERS.any? { |a| a.all? { |r,c| @cells[r][c] == side } }
  end

  def self.show
    3.times do |i|
      puts "%s|%s|%s" % @cells[i]
      puts "_____" unless i == 2
    end
  end                 
end
```

See [Array::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-c-new), [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) and [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F).

```
class Player
  def initialize(side)
    @side = side
  end

  def move(r,c)
    Board.record_move(r,c,@side)
  end

  def win?
    Board.win?(@side)
  end
end
```

```
x = Player.new('X')
  #=> #<Player:0x000057c0e95c4430 @side="X"> 
o = Player.new('O')
  #=> #<Player:0x000057c0e95e3100 @side="O">
```

```
Board.show
 | | 
_____
 | | 
_____
 | |
```

```
x.move 0,2
Board.show
 | |X
_____
 | | 
_____
 | |
```

```
o.move 0,0
Board.show
O| |X
_____
 | | 
_____
 | |
```

```
x.move 2,0
Board.show
O| |X
_____
 | | 
_____
X| | 
x.win? #=> false
```

```
o.move 2,2
Board.show
O| |X
_____
 | | 
_____
X| |O
o.win? #=> false
```

```
x.move 1,1
Board.show
O| |X
_____
 |X| 
_____
X| |O
x.win? #=> true
```